# RDP connection using codding language

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I was wondering how can we make connection to an RDP using ip:port/user/password

through any coding language that works online like this website https://www.allmydesktops.com/

what is the idea for that or at least how to check that user and password is correct for an RDP ip using coding language

Comment: Typically the first step in implementing a protocol is to read the specification. This looks like it's gonna be a quite complicated/large protocol: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af15dea6-c0c0-440e-b432-783edc4b8526/rdp-protocol-specification?forum=os_specifications